# Is It safe to delete all files/directories from /tmp folder on ubuntu 14.04 rackspace server?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rackspace, tmp

I am getting error unable to connect with mysql. when I googled I found It's because of size. It's showing /tmp 100% used. so can I completely remove all files from/tmp folder ?

```
#df -m /tmp

 Filesystem     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on

 /dev/xvda1         40184 38508         0 100% /
```

I have following files

> stderr (44.3 KB)
>
> file7bJPfk (0B)

```
root@cloud-server-02:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       40G   38G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            988M   12K  988M   1% /dev
tmpfs           200M  408K  200M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            999M     0  999M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

although I have removed 1GB of data still is shows 100% use

Comment: Your `/` file system is full,  `/tmp` is only a subdir of that.

Comment: thanks @Sven although i have deleted 500MB data from 4)Gb server still it shows 100% when i do df -h?

Answer (score 3):

Stop you critical services and cleanup folder. The tmp directory is cleared by default at every boot. During deletion you may face with files which are in use, you can skip them.

Comment: Let me clearify something....Clearing of /tmp area is NOT automatic nor default as this depends on how the system is put configured.  If /tmp is configured in the swap space this is basically an artifact of rebooting, but the startup scripting does not do this.  If /tmp is resident on a standard filesystem, then the files/directories persist between reboots.

Comment: By default files in tmp deletes at every boot. Check /etc/default/rcS